# How do I create Application Server Cartridge for WSO2 Stratos 2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

everyone
Could someone show me detail how to create Application Server Cartridge for WSO2 Stratos 2.0?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/WSO2+Application+Server+Express+Guide) sample that is available in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these blogs one by one, then you have to learn these techniques to add to your problem

[How to install apache stratos](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/04/installing-apache-stratos-40-with.html)

[how cartridges use in apache strtos](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/04/using-cartridges-in-apache-stratos-40.html)

[how to create sample mongoDB cartridge in apache stratos](http://blog.ravihansa3000.com/2014/04/creating-and-using-mongodb-cartridge-on.html)

Follow above articles and will get a broad knowledge in apache startos. Hope this helps